# Chrome ARC SDCard Location

Tags: google-chrome-arc

When you add your apk to ARC on a PC and enter

```
{"enableExternalDirectory": true}
```

it will prompt you for the local directory that you want to use as your SDCard location.  After the user selects that directory, where does ARC write that value (the folder path)?  I looked in Manifest.json but it didn't have the selected folder path, it just has "enableExternalDirectory": true, but not the folder path the user chose.  Is there a config file somewhere that has it?

Answer (score 0):

[image: View Screenshots]

After you choose your apk, modify the Additional Metadata as `{"enableExternalDirectory": true}`,then test your app, a file browser will open, then select the dictionary.